# CBR and CBZ files read with Java

Tags: java

Someone know how can i manipulate .cbr and .cbz file? Has some library?

Answer (score 3):

A `.cbr` file is a rar archive, and a `.cbz` file is a zip archive.  Inside the archive are a bunch of image files.  You can use whatever tools/utilities you would normally use for rar/zip files to get inside the archives and deal with the images directly.

Answer (score 3):

cbr is actually just a rar file, and cbz is regular zip files, you can manipulate zip file using java.util.zip API
You can also take a look at Jomic source code for implementation http://jomic.sourceforge.net/

Jomic is cbz, cbr, and pdf comic reader made using Java